# TYPO3 Powermail access values directly

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, powermail

in TYPO3 powermail receiver body there is a

```
{powermail_all}
```

to print all the input variables into the body of the receivers mail.

is there an possibility to only print some of the input values?

something like

```
{powermail_firstname}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use {firstname} or something like {markername} in RTE, Mail templates, subject, etc...

Comment: do I have to change the template or is it enough to just create a new text input and then us a markername?

Comment: Every input-field gets its own markername (you can change it if you want). So if you add another input-field, you have another markername. And yes, you can use it in the RTE or in the Mail-template or anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForEditors/AddANewPlugin/Index.html#id2), this would be possible with `{firstname}`.